# Error when returning model.ToListAsync();

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I had this working:

```
private readonly SuperContext _context;
public EmployeesController(SuperContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        var names = from m in db.Employee
                    select m;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            names = names.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
                                || s.LastName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return View(await names.ToListAsync());
    }
```

But now I am getting this error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HL3AAH6GJBIP": An unhandled exception was thrown by the     
application.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.
at LRClinicSuperWP.Controllers.EmployeesController.<Index>d__3.MoveNext() in   
    H:\VSProjectP\src\Project\Controllers\EmployeesController.cs:line 35
```

Line 35 is the return statement, so something is amiss with the IQueryable names. The database has 3 test entries in it and other queries against the same model are working in other controllers in the project, just not this one.

**What would cause an IQueryable to not return data from the database context?**

**UPDATE**

After spending some time debugging, I am seeing that the issue is not the IQueryable, but the model instead. db.Employee is not getting data from the database.

```
'((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.
IServiceProvider>)db.Employee).Instance' threw an exception of type  
'System.NotImplementedException'
```

I'm still looking through debug logs to find out why, but if someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Check out your `names.Where` expression. What would happen if there was an entry where `FirstName` had a `null` value? Or if `LastName` had a `null` value?

Comment: Not a duplicate. My question is "What would cause an IQueryable to not return data from the database context?" I know what the error means, but as stated above, the database contains data and is being queried elsewhere in the project.

Comment: If there where an entry with FirstName or LastName were null, that would be a problem and cause a null exception. However, those columns are not nullable in the database and all 3 test examples have data in both columns.